# OpenOffice Calc complex functions

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm wanting to set up a Calc sheet that will offer me stock reorder points on items that sell at a fast rate. In other words, using =Wanted In Stock # - (cell quantity) lets me know if I need to reorder the item or not. I have set up an example of this to further explain what I'm looking for.

[image: Reorder Points]

The cells in Red tell me how many I need to order to maintain stock on hand wanted. Cells in Yellow show me I have plenty of stock in store, thus nothing to order.

The Yellow cells are just used for show and do not need anything else. The Red cells are what I'm wanting to get complex functions/formulas for. I'm wanting to do 3 things, if at all possible:

1. Have the Reorder columns hidden unless the item needs to be ordered. Though this isn't essential if it cannot be done
2. When items need to be reordered, have the column cell show with order count and have red background. Again not essential if cannot be done
3. Once finished with inventory on hand and reorder cells showing, then I would like a formula to print off a sheet showing the color, item # (306, 1041, etc), order quantity with red background. Those not needing to be reordered wouldn't appear on final order sheet. This on the other hand is really what I'm looking for

Is this at all possible? Or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this report is what you are looking for:

[image]

To do this, first arrange the data into a single table:

[image]

Then select the table (cells A1 to D9) and go to `Data -> Pivot Table -> Create`,  pressing OK to use the current selection.  Drag "Color" to Row Fields,  "Item" to Column Fields, and "Reorder" to Data Fields.  (For LibreOffice, if it says "Data" under Column Fields, select it and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to remove it.)  Expand "More" ("Options" in LibreOffice), uncheck Total Columns and Total Rows.  Then Press OK.

To hide everything that doesn't need to be reordered, right-click on the cell that says "Sum - Reorder" and choose `Filter...`.  Under `Field Name` select "Reorder".  Under `Condition` select ">", and set value to `0`.  Then press OK.

To practice using pivot tables, there is an example at http://dwmallisk.blogspot.com/2015/01/using-libreoffice-calc-to-create-pivot.html.

For more complex reports, it might be helpful to link your spreadsheet to the Base component of OpenOffice.

Comment: Definitely seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I have never used Pivot Tables before, but will give this a go and hopefully can figure it all out. Thanks Jim!